# Einstein Analytics Dashboard

Tags: einstein-analytics, dashboard, einstein-analytics-dashboards, tab-settings

I am trying to add multiple tabs in einstein dashboard but i'm not getting from where we can add multiple tabs in einstein dasboard anyone please help me out

Answer (score 0):

We have '+' on the dashboard where we can add multiple pages to the dashboard.

[image]

Please find the below help document for the same.

[Help Document](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_dashboard_pages.htm&type=5)